# SoftEther and radius auth failed even if radius responds ok

Tags: freeradius

Have a very specific issue.

server in radius is registered properly, firewall on vpn server is empty ( no blocks), freeradius responds to auth request with login ok but softehter fails with auth failed ( both openvpn and sstp ).

Has anyone encountered such issue?